# what is the meaning of user@DESKTOP - 6RBC9EL MINIGW64 ~?

Tags: git-bash

I am new to windows command line interface and after installing Git, my command line interface appears like one in the attached document.

May I ask what is the meaning of `python@DESKTOP - 6RBC9EL MINGW64 ~` ?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-bash%5D+prompt

Comment: It means you should set a better machine name than "DESKTOP - 6RBC9EL" -- perhaps something that's meaningful to you that you'll instantly recognize.

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of text/code/errors unless there is no other way. right now, your image is nearly unreadable and requires squinting or zooming in to read it ... and it is all text, so there is no _reason_ to post an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the PS1 prompt of git bash.

PS1 is a variable containing the prompt of the git bash console. You can later change it. To know how to change it, visit https://alanbarber.com/post/how-to-customize-the-git-for-windows-bash-shell-prompt/

Here,

- "python" is your user name.
- "DESKTOP-6RBC9EL" is the computer name.
- "~" is the current directory interpreted in bash.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. It cleared my doubt.